# Swift Console Output to Text Label

Tags: json, swift, xcode, console, uilabel

I am trying to take console output from a json request and post it as a text label for the user. I can't seem to get it to work. Any advice? Thanks! It prints fine in the console, but won't work for the "self.resultLabel.text = json"

```
do {
    let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:.AllowFragments)

    print(json)

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{            
        self.myActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()            
        self.myImageView.image = nil; 
        self.resultLabel.text = json

        func loadSites(){                
            //trying to get the post to show up in the place of the invisible label             
        }            
    });

}catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: label.text requires a string and json is not exactly a string. Have you tried json.description instead?

Comment: Thanks so much for your response Alex. It looks like this fixes the error: self.resultLabel.text = (json as AnyObject).description

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why exactly you want to show raw json to users in UILabel but you should convert json to a string if you want to assign it to UILabel's `text` property.

There is a `description` method, which is always used in Objective-C whenever you print an NSObject subclass via NSLog. 
This method is also available in Swift:

```
self.resultLabel.text = (json as AnyObject).description
```